# NHibernate Envers: Auditing entity based on property value

Tags: c#, auditing, nhibernate-envers

I have a very specific need for auditing.

Consider the following class (I changed the name of my classes and trimmed unnecessary code for the sake of simplicity)

```
[Audited]
public class Client
{
  [NotAudited]
  public virtual IList<Order> Orders {get; set;}
}
```

The Client entity should only be audited when the Orders property is NOT empty.

Is that at all possible ? If so, how I would I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to turn off auditing in runtime based on some state, you can make your own custom subclass of `AuditEventListener`and pass an instance of that type into `IntegrateWithEnvers` method.

In your subclass, you can override `OnPostDelete`, `OnPostInsert`, `OnPostRecreateCollection`, `OnPostUpdate`, `OnPreRemoveCollection` and `OnPreUpdateCollection`. In your case, you should probably check `evt.Entity` and `evt.AffectedOwnerOrNull`. If you want to audit, simply call base method, if you don't want to audit do nothing in your implementation.

Note however that you should probably just doing this if you just use Envers for simple logging. If you use it to recreate historical instances, "removing" auditing for some historical events may cause problems when loading historical instances. If that's the case for you it's only safe to do this if an entity either has or hasn't got `Orders` for all its lifetime.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  The first part of your answer is great, the last paragraph not so much :)  I will need at some point to show a history log. So it's best if i log everything and I'll filter out the history log.